# Using different version of go package in single project

Tags: go

I am trying to use multiple version of a single go tool in one project. For example, here is a package: https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/pkg, now this package has some directories that are available in older versions, but not in current version and vice-versa. I want to use both, doing go get always gets the latest version. If I switch to old version, I miss out on the latest directories. Any idea how can I keep both the versions?

TIA.

Comment: What is missing from the later versions that you need? It’s possible that these parts were extracted to a new package rather than removed altogether. However if they were removed, it was likely for good reason

Comment: "how can I keep both the versions?" You cannot. Rework.

Comment: install two times golang in different locations, lets say one is 1.11 other one is 1.8 change the older one's compiler name go to go1.8 add then set them in path environment, call go1.8 for go version 1.8, call go for latest.

Comment: @RockOnGom two *package* versions, not two *Go* versions. And the Go 1 Compatibility Promise makes needing an older version of Go itself extremely unlikely.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible if major version of new and old releases is different with help of gopkg.in, you can import with different import path:

- https://gopkg.in/go-redis/redis.v2
- https://gopkg.in/go-redis/redis.v1

And then use them in Go separately:

```
import (
    redisv1 "gopkg.in/go-redis/redis.v1"
    redisv2 "gopkg.in/go-redis/redis.v2"
)
```

If major version is the same it's not possible to implement, since `go get`, `go modules` and other package managers do not support it.